# Regex that match spaces if not inside {...} in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to find Regular Expression that will match every space if it is not between { } in any combination. I have already come up with this one ```\s(?![^{]*})+``` but it's not working correctly!
link to image 
As you can see on the image its matching those spaces marked in red rectangle even though they are between { }, only not exatly between { } but between { { and that something that I do not want to... 
There are some examples to understand what regex I want because its a little but complex: 
1. 
```lol.something.xd 1 F 1.99 #adasdaops {something.awesome 4 8 9} null T;``` = Match every space here simply if not inside { }!

2. 
```lol.something.xd-1-F-1.99-#adasdpopu-{something.awesome 4 8 9 5 {#adsadasdasd} null F T {something.awesome.Foo 7 8 9 4545 T} null null F T}-45.5F-null-{alpha.beta.gama 45}-45-null;``` = Match only spaces that are represented as "-"

I need this regex to split Strings in Java if it matters. 

Note: Unfortunately, Java does not support recursive regex so keep it on mind in future answers!

Side Note: The web page is not showing code fences on my question from some reason. Maybe only I do not see it, but If you too and you know why then please fix it.

Comment: `/\{.*?\}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)| /`

Comment: The above will not behave well for nested braces, so here's one that does: `/(\{(?:(?>[^{}]+)|(?1))*\})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)| /` [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/G9jrId/1)

Comment: Not sure if `SKIP` and `FAIL` are supported in Java, if so then maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/TxOK08/16). If not supported, maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/TxOK08/17) is a good starting point?

Comment: Wow that was fast! But.... yes ur right SKIP and FAIL are not allowed in Java. Actually I do not see it anywhere before. Even https://regexr.com/ cant compile it. Strange that there is no unified regex for every prog language.

Comment: @JvdV that thing you have done actually works but only on your example. I need it to correctly match 2. point in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea for "match X, but not when it's inside Y" is to match Y, discard it, and then match X.

Matching arbitrarily nested braces is in itself no easy task, as it requires a recursive regex.

Here's a regex that should work for your needs, and some explanation:

```
/(\{(?:(?>[^{}]+)|(?1))*\})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)| /g
```

What a mess!

```
/
  ( # first subpattern
    \{ # match an opening brace
    (?: # subpattern
      (?> # atomic group (don't backtrack this, avoids Catastrophic Backtrack)
        [^{}]+ # match one or more non-brace characters
      )
    | # or...
      (?1) # recursively match the first subpattern (ie. nested braces)
    )* # zero or more times
    \} # match a closing brace
  )
  (*SKIP) # skip this part of the subject string
  (*FAIL) # always fails, which excludes the contents of the braces from the match
| # or (ie. if the skipped part doesn't happen)
[space] # match a space
/g # find all matches
```

However, not all flavours of regex support verbs like `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`, and others don't support recursive regexes. In these cases, you will need some kind of parser.

That's going to be more work, but the general idea will be to break your string down and go character-by-character. If it's a `{`, increment a counter. If it's `}`, decrease the counter. If it's a space, then do something with it *only* if the counter is zero.

Comment: As I have mentioned this one will not work. Java throws this: ```Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 20
/(\{(?:(?>[^{}]+)|(?1))*\})(*SKIP)(*FAIL)| 
                    ^```
\*Other stuff that is too long for comment on this web page\*

Comment: And what I know, Java default does not support recursive regex.

Comment: Could you use `\K` instead of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`?

Comment: @jdaz Doesn't matter, it throws exception already on ...(?1)... It did not even reach (*SKIP)(*FAIL). (?1) Is also from recursive regex...

Comment: I need this regex to split string in Java. I thought it will not be that complex and hard problem but it looks like it is. Maybe, would not be easier to write a method in Java that will do this??

Answer (score 0):

Finally I manage to solve this problem for my self!
Based on posted answers I realized that regex is not going to work in this case. So I decided to solve it using some regular Java stuff and I come up with this freak:

```
    public static String[] splitValues(String s)
{
    List<String> resault = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0, brackets = 0, lastIndex = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s.charAt(i) == ' ' && brackets == 0)
            resault.add(s.substring(lastIndex == 0 ? 0 : lastIndex + 1, lastIndex = i));
        else if (s.charAt(i) == '{')
            brackets++;
        else if (s.charAt(i) == '}')
        {
            if (brackets > 0)
                brackets--;
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unclosed or missing: { or } at index " + i);
        }
        
        if (i == s.length()-1 && brackets > 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unclosed or missing: { or }");
        else if (i == s.length()-1)
            resault.add(s.substring(lastIndex == 0 ? 0 : lastIndex + 1, s.length()));
    }
    
    return resault.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

It is ugly and long and also not solving the regex thing that I have originally asked but it solves the main problem for me and that is the point. But If somebody eventually finds a regex solution just feel free to post it! But after all, I simply do not think so it is possible because remember while posting Java has no recursive regex! 
Also, that function above is now a part of [SerialX](https://github.com/PetoPetko/Java-SerialX), one of my libs!